# PrimeFaces remote command is not invoking

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a remote Command button to execute a method to a bean level. But my command button is not working .

I am attaching my code below:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/layouts/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <div class="container">

        <script>

        function doAlert(s)
        {
            if(s=="true")
                {
                alert(s);
                rc();
                alert('hi i am');
                }
            else
                {
                 alert("Wrong Finger Print");
                }
        }

        </script>


          <h:form class="form-horizontal" id="myform" >
                <div class="row">

        <h:messages />
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="4" border="0" columnClasses="control-label">

            <h:outputText  value="Username :" />
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.login}" label="username" style="width: 200;" /> 
            <p:watermark for="username" value="Username" ></p:watermark>

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password :" />
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" label="password" style="width: 200;"/> 
            <p:watermark for="password" value="Password"></p:watermark>

            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
            <!-- <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.logMeIn}" widgetVar="mybutton" /> -->

            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.logMeIn}" widgetVar="mybutton"  disabled="#{!loginBean.enabled}"/>
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="loginButton" actionListener="#{loginBean.enableButton}" /> 
            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
            <h:outputText value="#{loginBean.enabled}"></h:outputText>
            <applet id="fingureprintapplet" name="fingureprint" codebase="classes"  code="fingerprintntscanner.MyClassApplet.class" archive="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/FIngerprintntScanner.jar,#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/lib/NBioBSPJNI.jar" width="300" height="400">

            </applet>
        </h:panelGrid>

        </div>
        </h:form>

        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My bean is:

```
     @ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationService}")
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService; // injected Spring defined service for bikes


    public String logMeIn() {

        boolean success = authenticationService.login(login, password);

        if (success){
            return "/faces/pages/home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"; // return to application but being logged now 
        }
        else{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login or password incorrect."));           
            return "/faces/login.xhtml";
        }
    }

    public String logout(){
        System.out.println("chandan");
        authenticationService.logout();
        return "/faces/pages/home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"; 
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



    public void setAuthenticationService(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public void enableButton() {
        System.out.println("chandan");
        enabled = true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(){
        System.out.println("value is");
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        System.out.println("value is sdgsdg");
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
```

Please check why my remote command is not working.

Comment: What exactly "is not working"? You are not even calling `doAlert` anywhere in the code. So what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Plus dat your bean name could be wrong, method name/signature could be wrong (so please post a minimal but fully valid bean to), you could have nested forms (from the template) so please create a reduced example...

Comment: @user1983983 i am calling rc(); inside my doAlert method and doAlertMethod has been called by the applet

Comment: @Kukeltje i am updating my question . please check the update

Comment: So `hi i am` is alerted as expected, but `value is` is not logged and the button is not getting updated?

Comment: @ user1983983 exactly why is not updating i am not finding out. have been trying for 3 days and could not find the error.

Comment: What do you want a `<p:remoteCommand>` to do? Do you want it to update a `<p:commandButton>` as identified by `loginButton`? I do not think what you want to do is this. The code symptoms however, indicate so. You are supposed to execute a JavaScript event on behalf of a `<p:remoteCommand> so that it can invoke an action(Listener) method in the associated backing bean as also demonstrated on the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml). "*RemoteCommand provides a simple way to execute backing bean methods with javascript.*".

Answer (score 10):

Use `process="@this"` and `partialSubmit="true"` on `remoteCommand`.